# z-index in SWT drawing?

Tags: java, swt

I'm using SWT to drawing something on a Canvas. But some others are also drawing on it and that will lead to wiping my contents. Is there something like z-index in HTML to help me always stay on top?

Answer (score 1):

**If** there are multiple paint listeners painting on the **same** canvas then Z-order wouldn't help you much anyhow. You could try to get your listener to be the last one added to the canvas, but the success of this depends on the details.